# For $f(x, y) = x-y$, is $f(K \times K)$ closed if $K$ is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functions, real-numbers

$f: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x, y) = x-y$. For $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ closed is $f(K\times K)$ closed?

For the closed interval this is straight forwardly true and $f([a, b] \times [a, b]) = [a-b, b-a]$. Furthermore $g:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ where $g(K) = f(K \times K)$ is an open map. This is true since any open set is the countable union of open intervals and $g((a, b)) = (a-b, b-a)$.

Comment: Can you post what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, for closed $K$, the set $f(K\times K)$ is not closed. A simple example:

$$K = \{ n + 2^{-(n+3)} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$

Then $1 \in \overline{f(K\times K)} \setminus K\times K$.